# Abnormality in Horse shoe magnet

Tags: electromagnetism

Recently while experimenting with force experienced by current carrying conductor, I came across a abnormality in the horse shoe magnet, due to which the direction of force on the current carrying conductor by the Flemings Left Hand Rule was false.

I noticed that when i kept a compass near the heads of the horse shoe magnet, the needle pointed from North Pole to South Pole of the magnet. But when it was kept between the two hands, it pointed from South Pole to North Pole.

[image]

I dont think it is theoretically possiblle that magnetic field is going from North to South outside the horse shoe whereas it is going from South to North between the two ends of the horse shoe.

Please explain this.

Comment: Frankly, the most likely reason is an error or mistake in your experimental setup.